# Zooming in MsChart

Tags: c#-4.0, mschart

I am working with MsChart control, C#, Visual Studio 2012. I faced the following problem.

I’d like to choose some interval on the X axis (which represent dates) of the stacked bar chart and to zoom it to a bigger scale. With first few steps I can do it, but as soon as my interval gets smaller, I can only choose of one full day. Using  chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 0  did not help me.

How do I choose smaller intervals (say it, hours, minutes, etc)?

Comment: Will that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626855/ms-chart-control-zoom-minsize-issue